Recurrence relation for orthogonal polynomials with power law weight function
The objective is to find the recurrence relation for orthogonal polynomials with respect to the scalar product:
$$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x) g(x) w(x) dx,$$
where $0<a<b<\infty$, $w(x)=x^{c}$, with $c=-H-1/2, H \in (0,1/2)$. In other words, given the three-term recurrence relation for monic polynomials,
$$ p_{r+1}(x) = \left( x -
\frac{\langle xp_r, p_r \rangle}{\langle p_r, p_r \rangle}
\right)p_r(x)- \frac{\langle p_r, p_r \rangle}{\langle p_{r-1}, p_{r-1} \rangle}p_{r-1}(x), \hspace{0.3cm} r=0,1,\ldots $$
where $p_{-1}(x) = 0$ and $p_0(x) = 1$, the aim is to find the explicit form of
$$ \alpha_r= \frac{\langle xp_r, p_r \rangle}{\langle p_r, p_r \rangle}, \hspace{0.5cm} \beta_r=\frac{\langle p_r, p_r \rangle}{\langle p_{r-1}, p_{r-1} \rangle}.$$
Inspired by this post https://oceanofmath.blog/?p=338, here there is my attempt:
$$ \langle xp_r, p_r \rangle = \int_a^b x^{c+1} p_r^2(x) dx = \frac{x^{c+2}}{c+2} p^2_r(x)\Big|_a^b - \int_a^b 2 p_r(x) p_r'(x) x^{c+1} dx $$
$$ \int_a^b 2 p_r(x) p_r'(x) x^{c+1} dx = 2\langle p_r, xp_r' \rangle = 2r\langle p_r, p_r \rangle $$
$$ \langle p_r, p_r \rangle = \frac{x^{c+1}}{c+1} p^2_r(x)\Big|_a^b - \int_a^b 2 p_r(x) p_r'(x) x^{c} dx $$
$$ \int_a^b 2 p_r(x) p_r'(x) x^{c} dx = 2\langle p_r, p_r' \rangle = 0,$$
therefore,
$$ \alpha_r= \frac{\langle xp_r, p_r \rangle}{\langle p_r, p_r \rangle} 
= \frac{c+1}{c+2} \frac{(b)^{c+2}p_r^2(b)-(a)^{c+2}p_r^2(a)}{(b)^{c+1}p_r^2(b)-(a)^{c+1}p_r^2(a)}$$
$$ \beta_r=\frac{\langle p_r, p_r \rangle}{\langle p_{r-1}, p_{r-1} \rangle} =
\frac{(b)^{c+1}p_r^2(b)-(a)^{c+1}p_r^2(a)}{(b)^{c+1}p_{r-1}^2(b)-(a)^{c+1}p_{r-1}^2(a)}.$$
Thank you!
